# custom select field populated by allocated post category

Tags: custom-field

I need to have several custom meta boxes in the post edit screen that allows the client to choose a particular page for the allocation of a blockquote.

ATM I have a template part called blockquote.php, that is called on various standard templates, for example, single.php calls it via a conditional.

```
<?php 
if ( in_category( 'nen-news' ) || in_category( 'news' ) )  : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/newsletter-signup-sidebar' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/blockquote' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>

<?php get_template_part('template-parts/blockquote'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/get-in-touch' ); ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

There are several files that call the template part blockquote.php .

The client requires 4 custom fields - title, quote, author and display page.

I can do the title, quote & author easily using custom meta boxes and the post_meta data.

The problem I have is that they also want to be able to choose a particular page to place the blockquote on. They want a dropdown selectbox, in the post edit screen with all the pages where a blockquote appears.

My problem is, how do I populate the select dropdown with the right choices.

How can I get the information from the WordPress core to populate the select dropdown as the site is  dynamic and they will be adding pages that will have the template part blockquote.php - so I cant just build a static dropdown - it needs to auto populate based on pages that display a blockquote.

When they add a new page that displays a blockquote, this then needs to be added to the select box as an option for placement.

This is stumping me - any ideas?

Comment: This is pretty complex, I think you need to parse the content and store it in a transient. Why don't you just make a taxonomy called blockquotes and ask them to click it, or have some javascript do it for them.

Comment: I am a bit confused with the question. Why not create a custom post type called quotes? Then you can add all your quotes there. In the other page you can a drop-down with the title of all quotes in that custom post type.

Comment: I am confused also. I suspect the approach itself is flawed but I can't quite work out what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I am trying to accomplish what the client is asking me for!! He wants to be able to write a testimonial blockquote, be able to give it a title, content and then an author. Then he also want to choose which page it goes on. I think the best approach here would be something along the lines of what gdaniel has proposed. Its more bottom up than top down. Which has miffed me because I usually like to most things bottom up - but as this is an addition to a 99% finished site my mindset is more 'tacking-on' that 'building-in'. Any discussion on gdaniel's idea?

Comment: @user1683285 - I typically user the plugin advanced custom fields to handle this kind of things. Create a custom post type first for all your quotes. Create a drop-down custom field that shows in every page edit. The plugin will allow you to build a drop-down of all posts in a custom post type automatically, saving you tons of time. Then it's just a matter of selecting which quote you want to show in each page. In your page template you can have a if statement. If custom_field == "" - don't print blockquote div.. else echo custom_field.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the first step of a problem I'm currently trying to figure out (specifically, I'm working on populating one select based on a post type, then populating a second select based on the post type selected).  If blockquote is a post type,I think it'll work.

Here's what I've worked out as part of my own project:

```
function fetch_ID_list($type) {
    // This function is known for corrupting the post ID for some reason.  Therefore I copy $post to $temp and reassert it prior to returning
    global $post;
    $temp = $post;

    $query_params = array(
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $all_posts = waka_taxonomy_query($type, -1, $query_params);

    $return = array();

    if($all_posts->have_posts()) {
        while ($all_posts->have_posts()) {
            $all_posts->the_post();

            $return[] = get_the_ID();
        }
    }

    $post = $temp; // Reassert original post

    return $return;
}
```

From there you can take the array provided and populate a select